# How much storage occupy the null field in sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Am using **SQL Server** as my project database.
Am having two type of forms in the project submitted by users.One of them is only with 40 fields.
And the an other one is having 120 fields.I want to store them in a single table because it is easy to find both forms of a single user.
but the most of the fields will be ***NULL*** for a type of form in those both (so in the table also **most of the columns will be null** for a type of form and for the an other type of form the will be some values)..Will they took any storage..Will it causes to increase size of database.
or else storing two forms data independently in individual tables is better idea to save database storage..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NULL` columns occupy no page storage except for a bit in the null bitmap, and that's present for all rows anyway. If you have many, many rows with mostly `NULL`s, you can save even that overhead by using [sparse columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns), but we're talking >50% of all rows here. A better question is whether your current way of storing values is appropriate in terms of maintenance -- instead of 120 columns, you could also store these values normalized in a table with key/value columns, so only values present get rows.

Comment: @JeroenMostert . . . Your comment is incorrect.  Zaynul's answer is correct.

Comment: My comment is incorrect for fixed-length columns -- that's true. For some reason I assumed form fields would be mostly or all variable length. That said, if you're storing 120 fixed-length values in a row and the majority are `NULL`, considering sparse columns becomes even more attractive.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert - Thank you for mentioning sparse columns. This is extremely useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All fixed-length columns reserve space in the row regardless of whether or not they allow NULL
If the field is variable width the NULL value takes up no space.
You can read this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc168f01-075f-4f29-a669-eba93b4db6a0/what-nullable-types-allocate-space-even-when-null?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

and another [discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0404de89-70dc-4026-9e2e-13ddc3e7c058/null-data-storage-sql-server-2008?forum=sqldatabaseengine) about this topics sql server blog

Comment: so can i store those both forms in a single table?..It will not misuse storage?

Comment: Links mentioned are not valid